# Contacts and objects in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, contact-deletion

I am still fuzzy on how contacts are calculated.

There are various objects in MC.  We have contact_salesforce object, account_salesforce object, user_salesforce, case etc.

I was told that contact_salesforce is the "main source" for billable contacts.

Basically I want to do a mass deletion of contacts on a different object where they have never been sent an email (leads).  If I delete them will this cause any major issues?  I understand there are fields/headers/attributes associated with this object, but I am ONLY DELETING the contacts.

Will this have any major impact?  Since we dont use these contacts (00q) I just want to make sure that this wont have any major issues

Further to that, I was told that if we delete contacts, there is some "backend" process that prevents them coming back to their original form in salesforce - is this true?

Has anyone here mass deleted contacts then wanted to use them in the future?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a contact, it first gets suppressed for 14 days (this value can be changed) and then it will be permanently deleted from MC and cannot be brought back. During these 14 days you can't send to them.

If these are synced contacts, i.e. bringing over from Sales Cloud it sounds like in your case, you should first delete them in Sales Cloud and then delete them in MC. If you don't, the synced contacts will come back alive at the next synce.

As for reusing the contacts, I recommend reading this article from SFDC about Contact and Subscriber Keys as it will give best practices for allowing contacts to be 'reintroduced' (search for reintroduced, fourth bullet in the last column). This is likely the backend process you're referring to, i.e. making sure a Key is not reused. If you create a brand new Lead or Contact, it will have a new Key -> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_best_practices.htm&type=5

Also, note that deleting a contact from Contacts only removes it from Sendable Data Extensions, not DEs that are not sendable.

Comment: Hmmm.  So I should pause the object syncing no?  We have a lead object.  I am just thinking of our other contacts have info in the lead object - is there a way to check?  

Like have any information on the lead object that we would need to use?

Comment: If you pause syncing I believe all syncing is paused, not just the Lead object. And I believe, once a Lead is converted to a Contact, the Lead is closed (but still in the system). Hopefully, there's no data in the Lead object that wasn't brought over to Accounts, Contacts and Opportunities when converted. As always, do an export of the Lead object before doing any deletion. And please upvote my answer if you can, I need the rep! Thanks